# How to Select from a pivot table in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot-table

i have two tables :

[image: Headers Table]

and

[image]

i need to get something like this:

```
HeaderID   |  Position1    |  IsSuccessful  |  Position2  |  IsSuccessful
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    24719  |     gold_box  |        true    |  propname25 |        false
    24720  |       beyond  |        false   |        wtv  |        false
    24721  |      red_box  |        false   |      wtv22  |         true
```

i managed this so far:

```
TRANSFORM Max(Proposals.PropName) AS MaxOfPropName
SELECT Headers.HeaderID
FROM Headers INNER JOIN Proposals ON Headers.ProposalID = Proposals.ProposalID
GROUP BY Headers.HeaderID
PIVOT Headers.Position;



HeaderID   |  Position1    |  Position2  |
------------------------------------------
    24719  |     gold_box  |  propname25 |
    24720  |       beyond  |        wtv  |
    24721  |      red_box  |      wtv22  |
```

now i'm thinking to select from the pivot table but it's not working, and couldn't find any documentation on that on the net, for example:

```
select * from (
   TRANSFORM Max(Proposals.PropName) AS MaxOfPropName
   SELECT Headers.HeaderID
   FROM Headers INNER JOIN Proposals ON Headers.ProposalID = Proposals.ProposalID
   GROUP BY Headers.HeaderID
   PIVOT Headers.Position;
 )
```

Is there a way to use the results of the pivot table in another select query (ms access)? and how?
later on i'll have to use a single query with like 7 tables and joining them with an additional 3 pivot tables... :) I'm sorry guys for this question, but i'm stuck

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding derived table subqueries with two inner joins to the saved crosstab query for each Position. If more, positions exist, add more subqueries.

**CrossTab** Query *(save as separate query to be used in main query below)*

```
TRANSFORM Max(Proposals.PropName) AS MaxOfPropName 
SELECT Headers.HeaderID 
FROM Headers 
INNER JOIN Proposals ON Headers.ProposalID = Proposals.ProposalID 
GROUP BY Headers.HeaderID 
PIVOT Headers.Position
```

**Main** Query

```
SELECT crosstabQ.HeaderID, crosstabQ.Position1, pos1.IsSuccessful, 
       crosstabQ.Position2, pos2.IsSuccessful 
FROM (crosstabQ    

INNER JOIN    
   (SELECT IsSuccessful 
    FROM Headers
    WHERE Position = 1) AS pos1
ON pos1.HeaderID = crosstabQ.HeaderID)

INNER JOIN    
   (SELECT IsSuccessful
    FROM Headers
    WHERE Position = 2) AS pos2    
ON crosstabQ.HeaderID = pos2.HeaderID
```

---

Alternatively, run conditional aggregates which is the generalized version for pivot queries (here boolean values will return as integer, 0 or -1):

```
SELECT Headers.HeaderID, 
       Max(IIF(Headers.Position=1, Proposals.PropName, NULL)) As Position1,
       Max(IIF(Headers.Position=1, Headers.IsSuccessful, NULL)) As IsSuccessful1,
       Max(IIF(Headers.Position=2, Proposals.PropName, NULL)) As Position2,
       Max(IIF(Headers.Position=2, Headers.IsSuccessful, NULL)) As IsSuccessful2
FROM Headers 
INNER JOIN Proposals ON Headers.ProposalID = Proposals.ProposalID 
GROUP BY Headers.HeaderID
```

Comment: thank you man, but my main problem is that i'm writing in Ms-Access. And he doesn't like to tell him " Select From ( a pivot )"

Comment: Indeed, an MS Access limitation. Save the pivot as separate saved query and reference it in main.

Comment: yep :) that's what i did yesterday, though i'm very disappointed, but at least jet oledb and access are pretty compatible for that, thanks

Comment: Access' SQL engine is Jet/ACE (Windows .dll files). Did you see my edited answer which I tested on my end on other data? What error are you receiving? And why not use alternative answer?

Comment: i already did similar to your answer yesterday and it worked. i'm disappointed that i had to make the transforms in seperate queries. but since i was able to use them from C# all my problems are solved. and performance seems good